# how to communicate hosts in different subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

We have two subnets
Router 1

```
192.168.2.1
255.255.254.0
```

Router 2

```
192.168.1.1
255.255.255.0

 Modem >> switch 
        >> router1 wan port  >> from lan port to switch >> Different computers
        >> router2 wan port  >> from lan port to switch >> Different computers
```

Please note two different static public ips(of same subnet) for both routers.

I would like to know how I can access a host from Router 1 to a host in Router 2 or vice-versa.

Comment: I doubt such layout will work. If thouse routers are typical DSL routers or the like, then they will block all traffic to address families like 192.168. since those are considered local. They simply will drop packages they cannot route locally, which in their eyes in on the lan side. If on the other hand you have access to the routing tables of those routers, then where is the problem? The switch will forward packages correctly. But the routers must accept packages to the internal ip addresses from the wlan interfaces. I doubt tht is the case. The packages will be dropped as "aliens".

Comment: Why those two routers at all? Should one router be capable of managing _both_ networks if the net mask is correct? `Modem >> router >> switch >|> lan1|lan2`. Note that you can specify a different network mask on router and PC systems.

Comment: I don't know about this model. How can I have lan1 and lan2 from a single router?

Comment: Why not? From the routers point of view it is just a single lan.

Comment: can you give me an example of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a single router:

```
Modem >> router >> switch >> lan1 >> computers in lan1
                          >> lan2 >> computers in lan2
```

You don't even need two LANs formally, since the PCs don't need a special routing rule to reach all local systems in this case.

You use two address sets: 192.168.1.xxx and 192.168.2.xxx and a network mask of /23 or even /16, no difference there. This way all PCs know they can simply send out packages to everything inside 192.168... Whereas for packages outside they need a rule routing those packages through the router. The routing of packages between the two areas on the LAN side is done automatically by the switch. That is what a switch is build for.

Comment: Sorry, just now saw your condition of _two_ static IP addresses for the two routers... Is that really required?

Comment: Not necessary, but I would like to know what you mean by lan1 and lan2. Do you want me to place two additional routers connecting to the switch? And one will be Lan1 and another one will be Lan2

Comment: No, what would you need those routers for? You only need the router too access the WAN area (if at all). Communication between the two LANs can be handled by the switch. Why not? Note that a LAN is nothing specially managed or explicitly handled. Every network package carries a destination address where it will be delivered to. You only need a router if you have to _modify_ that address, rewrite it. For example in case of a NAT strategy to connect an internal LAN to the internet without having routable addresses for all LAN nodes. But internally all systems can communicate freely.

Comment: Suppose the first router lan ip is 192.168.2.1 and subnet mask 255.255.254.0. I can have ip address between 2.2 -2.254 and 3.1 to 3.254.right?
I have some set of computers which I want ip between 2.2 to 2.254 (lan1)
Another set of computers which I want ip address 3.1 to 3.254 i.e. called Lan2..how I can done that?

Comment: If you really insist on that subnet mask then you will have to use additional routers, indeed. Why don't you lift that mask to something like /22 (255.255.252.0)? That gives you a bigger LAN where you don't need any routers for internal traffic. You can use addresses from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.3.254.

Answer (score 1):

*This is an explanation of how you would do it assuming that you **must** keep these as two separate subnets!*

That is, you'll have to set up access for each IP address in the other router's firewall, and then specify to which internal system it will connect.

**Note:** It's only safe to do this because you have two *static* IP addresses!  There really isn't an easy, *safe* way to do this with dynamic IPs.

In that case, Router 1 will have to grant access to Router 2's public IP address and vice versa.  How you do this completely dependent on the make and model of the router.

The routers will know how to route to each other, because they'll be using the public IPs.

So, the data path will be: System1 (subnet1)->Router1->Internet->Router2->System2

Since different routers have you specify addresses in different ways, make sure you know how yours expects you to input the address or range of addresses.

However, that's not enough.  Because you have multiple systems on each subnet, all sharing the same public IP address, you also have to specify which inbound traffic goes to what subnet host.

That is, you start on System1 in the above data path.  The data goes out Router1 and back into Router2.  How does Router2 know where to send it?  It only has ONE external IP address.

Again, there are different ways of doing this for different routers.  On some, you can specify that data on certain ports gets sent to certain systems.  (Port Forwarding)

Using Telnet as an example (you **shouldn't**!  Telnet isn't secure.  It's just easy to use as an example)...

You want to get from System1 (on subnet1) to System3 (subnet2).

On Router1 you specify that incoming data on Port 23 (Telnet port) should go to System1.  On Router2 you send all Port 23 data to System3.

Port Forwarding, however, is somewhat limited insofar as, in the setup above, *only* System1 and System3 can receive Telnet data.

The other common way to do this is to have all data from a particular IP sent to one particular system on your subnet.  That won't work for you, because you have multiple systems on *each* subnet!

I hope this isn't **too** non-specific!  (Or too rambling!  :-) )  I'm trying to be as non-specific as possible, but it makes it difficult to explain things!  Unfortunately, since each company's routers use different interfaces, it's impossible for me to exactly what you need to do!

Let us know what your routers are.  Then I can possibly be more specific.

In the meantime, however, look for the sections in your router to 1) the other router's data in, and 2) specify what data goes to which system on the subnet!

I hope this helps!